# PostgreSQL: How to avoid division by zero when using case statements

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to divide two case statements. How do I avoid the occasional division by zero? I couldn't seem to figure out the `NULLIF` method.

```
 SELECT
           ROUND(100 * SUM(CASE WHEN be.event IN ('a') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / SUM(CASE WHEN be.event IN ('b', 'a') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 2)  AS "% Instant Book Today"
    FROM booking_events be
    WHERE
          be.created_at >= current_date AND
          be.created_at < current_date + interval '1 day';
```

What is the most efficient way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `NULLIF()` as:

```
SELECT ROUND(100 * SUM(CASE WHEN be.event IN ('a') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / 
                   NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN be.event IN ('b', 'a') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0), 2
            ) AS "% Instant Book Today"
```

Or, alternatively, the denominator is always non-negative, just remove the `ELSE 0`:

```
SELECT ROUND(100 * SUM(CASE WHEN be.event IN ('a') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / 
                   SUM(CASE WHEN be.event IN ('b', 'a') THEN 1 END), 2
            ) AS "% Instant Book Today"
```

Or, write the query as:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN be.event IN ('a') THEN 100.0 ELSE 0 END),
             2) as "% Instant Book Today"
FROM booking_events be
WHERE be.created_at >= current_date AND
      be.created_at < current_date + interval '1 day' AND
      be.event IN ('a', 'b');
```

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed answer. How would I go about returning `0` instead of `NULL`?